# How to Stop a Windows Service for long running Jobs?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler

Currently I am using Windows Service to keep on running some jobs in the background. These jobs are scheduled via Quartz.Net. Generally these are long running jobs, spans from 5 min to 15 min. If a job is currently running and if User will try to Shutdown the Windows Service then it throws Exception: **Windows service did not respond in a timely fashion.**

Actually OnShutdown() method of WindowsService, I am trying to Shutdown the Quartz.Net also.
I am calling **scheduler.Shutdown(true)** to stop the scheduler & wait for running jobs. If I will make this False then Windows Service Stops normally but it will put the running Job in Unstable state. Please help me on this.

Comment: you get the error "windows service did not respond in a timely fashion" because your main thread is processing the job you scheduled on it. If a user shuts down the service, the framework expects it to respond to the shutdown command. If you'd execute the job on a separate thread, then you'd be able to cancel the processing on the job, and respond to the "shutdown" command in time. Would that be an option?

Comment: Ya, that could be an option. It will Stop the Service normally but what will happen to the Running jobs? If the job will remain in Running State then if User will try to re-Start the Windows Service then what would be the scenario?

Comment: Well, I never used Quartz before, but it has its own API to control scheduled jobs. If you would go for the cancellation approach, would it be possible to program the behavior how to deal with the running job?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get this error because your service did not complete the Stop in the agreed-upon time.  So, the SCM assumes it's hung in some way and aborts it.

To tell the SCM you need more time to complete the operation, call `ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime()` in your `OnStop` handler.  For more information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime.aspx